# Vuex freezing when modifying reactive state properties

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am fairly new to Vuex, and have ran into a problem I can't diagnose. My store is set up similarly to the [Shopping example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart), and I've included the relevant module below.

The `INIT` action is called when the app loads, and everything functions fine. The `LOOKUP` action is later called from components, but freezes when calling the `define` mutation.

The current code is after trying several workarounds. Ultimately I'm trying to access `state.pages` from a component. I thought that the problem could've been because `state.pages` is an Object, so I made it non-reactive, and tried to make the component watch for changes in the `pageCounter` to retrieve the new page, but that didn't work.

I can include any other relevant information.

EDIT: Simplified the code to show more specific what the problem is.

store/modules/flashcards.js

```
// initial state
const state = () => ({
    counter: 0,
  })
  
  // actions
  const actions = {
  }
  
  // mutations
  const mutations = {
    increaseCounter(state) {
      console.log(state.counter)
      state.counter++;           <----------- Code stops here
      console.log(state.counter)
  }
  
  export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
  }
```

The component that accesses the store:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <md-button @click='increaseCounter'>Test</md-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import FlashCardComponent from './FlashcardComponent'
    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                counter: state => state.flashcards.counter
            })
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations('flashcards', ['increaseCounter']),
</script>
```

In `increaseCounter`, the first `console.log(state.counter)` is printed, but the second one isn't. This is a very simple access pattern, so I would appreciate insight into why it's giving this error.

Comment: First, note that your initial `state` does not contain a `pages` element. This is very suspicious. Second, please show the code that accesses `state.pages`. That code is modifying something and that triggers this error.

Comment: I removed ```pages``` in favor of ```pageCounter``` to simplify debugging. I further simplified the code, reflected in the original question. I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. <strike>The `strict` flag was being used when creating the Store object. Everything worked once I removed that.</strike> As Tordek said, don't do this.

I suppose I need to figure out *why* that's a problem, as it points to the state being manipulated outside of a mutation.

Comment: This is not a fix. If your code fails when the `strict` flag is enabled, you have some invalid access pattern in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I should’ve worded my answer better. I don’t consider it a true fix by any means, but rather it helped me proceed for now until I figure out where that invalid access pattern is located.